# Rails "update_attributes" skipping validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following simplified model:

```
class User
  attr_accessible :password
  validates :password, :presence => true
  validates_confirmation_of :password, :length => { :minimum => 4 }
end
```

That's pretty straight forward.  I'm testing it with RSpec/FactoryGirl, and have the following tests:

```
it "cannot create with password < 4 characters" do
  expect{ model = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :password => "12", :password_confirmation => "12") }.to raise_error
end

it "cannot update to password < 4 characters" do
  model = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  model.should be_valid
  model.update_attributes({:password => "12", :password_confirmation => "12"})
  model.reload
  model.password.should_not eq("12")
end
```

However, the second test fails.  For some reason, "12" seems to be able to be saved into the database as a valid password.  Why?  The API states that `update_attributes` should not bypass any of the validations!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is skipping validations.

I suspect this:

```
model.update_attributes({:password => "12", :password_confirmation => "12"})
```

is returning false.  Password is probably not a column in your database, rather you probably have crypted_password and password_salt so reloading it does not read the password from the database (this would be bad)

Also, you probably want :

```
attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation
```

Comment: Ok, I've checked it, and you are correct.  I've added `model.save` to the test, which throws an error.

I am concerned that reload isn't actually updating the dirty fields though.  That seems like undesired behaving (as in, literally the opposite of what I expect reload to do), but that's a separate issue.

Comment: You can also do model.update_attributes! which will raise instead of returning true or false.

Comment: Ah, that does make sense.  Thanks for the followup!